# pushSharpでCryptographicExceptionが発生します。

Tags: ios, c#, visual-studio, push-notification

Visual Studio 2013のC#で開発しております。

PushSharpを利用してIOSのプッシュサーバを作成しておりますが、
appleSettings = new PushSharp.Apple.ApplePushChannelSettings(appleCert, "xxxxxxx");
でCryptographicExceptionが発生しております。
何が原因でどうしたら解決できるのか教えてください。

エラー発生時のスクリーンショットです。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

下は自分のコードです。

```
    private static PushSharp.Apple.ApplePushChannelSettings appleSettings = null;
    private static PushSharp.Apple.ApplePushChannelSettings GetAppleSettingsDebug()
    {
        if (appleSettings == null)
        {
            // TODO : 設定値
            var appleCert = File.ReadAllBytes(@"D:\APNs\development.p12");
            appleSettings = new PushSharp.Apple.ApplePushChannelSettings(appleCert, "xxxxxxx");
        }
        return appleSettings;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`X509Certificate2`コンストラクター](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/ms148422.aspx)で例外が発生していると思われます。メッセージからしてこの場合はMSDNの

> 証明書のパスワードが正しくありません。

に該当するのではないでしょうか。

なお他の原因である可能性もありますので、まずは「詳細の表示…」でスタックトレースを確認してください。そこに`X509Certificate2..ctor`が含まれていれば上記の理由だと考えられます。